# Resume release from a particular project when doing a release:perform to a staging repo in Nexus

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I'm trying to do a release to a Nexus staging repo but it keeps dying at random points during the uploading of artifacts (debugging the "random points" is a separate issue). I'd like to be able to resume the release from the project that the died during upload with a command like:

```
mvn clean release:perform -Papache-release -Darguments="-rf :jclouds-jsch -DskipTests" -DconnectionUrl=scm:git:file://`pwd`/.git -Dtag=jclouds-1.7.3-rc1
```

Unfortunately the -rf in the command above doesn't work.

How can you do this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of using a staging repo is that you dont have to muck around with this. Instead just drop the staging repo and do a fresh full build and deployment from a consistent SCM revision.